# Proof that Laplace equation permits no local maxima

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

I glanced at a proof of the uniqueness theorem for Laplace's equation which implicitly relied on the non-existence of local maxima in the solution, and realized I didn't know how to prove that very basic result. It's something I've always taken for granted and never bothered to investigate. I don't have extensive formal education in PDEs, but ought to be able to prove at least that much. Any hints are appreciated.

I did a quick search on Google and the StackExchange, and didn't find anything, but I may have missed something.

Thanks

Comment: There is a simpler argument that starts like this. Suppose for contradiction there is max or min. By the second derivative test, the determinant of the hessian must be positive. You can check the determinant is $ f_{xx} f_{yy} - f_{xy}^2  = -f_{xx}^2 - f_{xy}^2 < 0 $, where I used $f_{xx} + f_{yy} = 0 $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a consequence of the [mean value property of harmonic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function): if $\Delta f=0$,
$$ f(x,y) = \frac{\int_{\partial B} f(u,v)\,d\mu}{\int_{\partial B} 1\,d\mu}$$
where $B$ is any ball centered at $(x,y)$ inside the domain of $f$. It follows that the extremal values of a non-constant harmonic function are always attained on the boundary of the domain.